# Sitecore reindexing fails with no error/log after SC7 upgrade

Tags: lucene, sitecore

I've spent a few days working on our SC7 upgrade (from Sitecore 6.6) and I'm running into an issue rebuilding the indexes (Sitecore desktop > control panel > indexing > indexing manager > web > rebuild).

I've stopped our various scheduled tasks and am using a private instance of SC, so there are no users or processing snuffling about in the way.  Prior to rebuilding, I stop IIS/worker processes and delete any existing index files on the filesystem.

The indexing will begin, and the wizard will update on progress to about 15,000 (out of 20,000 items).  At that point it will just start going slower and slower, before stopping.  Sometimes the CPU maxes out and stays there.  Sometimes the RAM fills up.  Sometimes w3wp crashes with a heep corruption error.  Usually (4/5 times) it just stops and goes no further.

The log and the Crawler log don't seem show anything unusual.  There are a couple of messages about large MP4 videos that can't be resized, and some binary files that can't have their content indexed.  Sitecore just seems to stop and restart (a new log file is started and contains the standard SC 'boot up' messages).

Log:

```
ManagedPoolThread #9 17:23:44 INFO  Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_web_index
ManagedPoolThread #11 17:23:50 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #11 17:24:55 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #11 17:24:55 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #4 17:25:55 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #4 17:25:55 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #1 17:27:00 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #1 17:27:00 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #1 17:27:00 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #1 17:27:00 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
12088 17:27:54 ERROR Could not resize image as it was larger than the maximum size allowed for memory processing. Media item: {0} [/sitecore/media library/Files/[MP4 film]?sc_database=web]
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:28:05 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:28:05 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:28:05 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:28:05 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:29:05 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:29:05 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:29:05 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:29:05 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
1668 17:29:13 ERROR Could not resize image as it was larger than the maximum size allowed for memory processing. Media item: {0} [/sitecore/media library/Files/[MP4 film]?sc_database=web]
1668 17:29:33 ERROR Could not resize image as it was larger than the maximum size allowed for memory processing. Media item: {0} [/sitecore/media library/Files/[MP4 film]?sc_database=web]
1668 17:29:43 ERROR Could not resize image as it was larger than the maximum size allowed for memory processing. Media item: {0} [/sitecore/media library/Files/[MP4 film]?sc_database=web]
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:30:06 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:30:06 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:30:06 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:30:06 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
7780 17:30:50 ERROR Could not resize image as it was larger than the maximum size allowed for memory processing. Media item: {0} [/sitecore/media library/Files/[MP4 film]?sc_database=web]
ManagedPoolThread #7 17:31:06 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #7 17:31:06 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #7 17:31:06 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #7 17:31:06 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #2 17:32:06 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #2 17:32:06 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #2 17:32:06 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #2 17:32:06 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
Heartbeat 17:32:49 WARN  Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
Heartbeat 17:32:49 INFO  Health.PrivateBytes: 0
Heartbeat 17:32:49 INFO  Health.CacheInstances: 95
Heartbeat 17:32:49 INFO  Health.CacheTotalCount: 70,442
Heartbeat 17:32:49 INFO  Health.CacheTotalSize: 78,936,852
Heartbeat 17:32:49 WARN  Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
Heartbeat 17:32:51 WARN  Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
ManagedPoolThread #19 17:32:51 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #19 17:32:51 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: core
ManagedPoolThread #19 17:32:51 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #19 17:32:51 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #3 17:32:51 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.TaskDatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #3 17:32:51 INFO  Processing tasks (count: 1)
ManagedPoolThread #3 17:32:51 INFO  Executing email reminder task
ManagedPoolThread #3 17:32:56 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.TaskDatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #14 17:33:06 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #14 17:33:06 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #14 17:33:06 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #14 17:33:06 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #12 17:34:06 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #12 17:34:06 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #12 17:34:06 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #12 17:34:06 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #7 17:35:07 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #7 17:35:07 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #7 17:35:07 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #7 17:35:07 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #18 17:36:07 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #18 17:36:07 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #18 17:36:07 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #18 17:36:07 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:37:07 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:37:07 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:37:07 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #16 17:37:07 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #8 17:37:52 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent
ManagedPoolThread #8 17:37:52 INFO  Scheduling.UrlAgent started. Url: http://local/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx
Heartbeat 17:37:53 WARN  Sitecore has no necessary permissions for reading/creating counters.
2080 17:38:25 INFO  Cache created: 'GeoIp' (max size: 1MB, running total: 799MB)
ManagedPoolThread #8 17:38:26 INFO  Scheduling.UrlAgent done (received: 426 bytes)
ManagedPoolThread #8 17:38:26 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #0 17:38:31 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #0 17:38:31 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #0 17:38:31 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #0 17:38:31 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #4 17:39:31 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #4 17:39:31 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #4 17:39:31 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #4 17:39:31 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #3 17:40:31 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #3 17:40:31 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #3 17:40:31 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #3 17:40:31 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #2 17:41:32 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #2 17:41:32 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: web
ManagedPoolThread #2 17:41:32 INFO  Examining schedules (count: 0)
ManagedPoolThread #2 17:41:32 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
```

Crawler:

```
12332 17:22:50 INFO  [Index=sitecore_web_index] Initializing OnPublishEndAsynchronousStrategy.
12332 17:22:50 INFO  [Index=sitecore_web_index] Initializing SitecoreItemCrawler. DB:web / Root:/sitecore
ManagedPoolThread #9 17:23:44 WARN  [Index=sitecore_web_index] Reset Started
ManagedPoolThread #9 17:23:44 WARN  [Index=sitecore_web_index] Reset Ended
ManagedPoolThread #9 17:23:44 WARN  [Index=sitecore_web_index] Full Rebuild Started
9828 17:23:57 ERROR Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField: _content for indexable: sitecore://web/{2199D684-1240-4702-B1AD-98CA54A482CD}?lang=en&ver=1
Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Message: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IPersistFile.Load(String pszFileName, Int32 dwMode)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Extracters.IFilterTextExtraction.FilterLoader.LoadAndInitIFilter(String fileName, String extension)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Extracters.IFilterTextExtraction.FilterReader..ctor(String fileName)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemIFilterTextExtractor.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneDocumentBuilder.AddComputedIndexFields()

11652 17:24:18 ERROR Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField: _content for indexable: sitecore://web/{87B6F986-53D4-4D87-9531-6CE90F684DC8}?lang=en&ver=1
Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Message: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004170C
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IPersistFile.Load(String pszFileName, Int32 dwMode)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Extracters.IFilterTextExtraction.FilterLoader.LoadAndInitIFilter(String fileName, String extension)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Extracters.IFilterTextExtraction.FilterReader..ctor(String fileName)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemIFilterTextExtractor.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneDocumentBuilder.AddComputedIndexFields()

6316 17:24:53 INFO  [Index=sitecore_core_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy executing.
6316 17:24:53 INFO  [Index=sitecore_core_index] History engine is empty. Incremental rebuild returns
6268 17:25:55 INFO  [Index=sitecore_core_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy executing.
6268 17:25:55 INFO  [Index=sitecore_core_index] History engine is empty. Incremental rebuild returns
9736 17:26:55 INFO  [Index=sitecore_core_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy executing.
9736 17:26:55 INFO  [Index=sitecore_core_index] History engine is empty. Incremental rebuild returns
6316 17:27:50 INFO  [Index=sitecore_web_index] TimeIntervalCommitPolicy.ShouldCommit - Time Limit Exceeded, lastCommit=20/02/2015 17:22:50, count=13635
6316 17:27:50 INFO  [Index=sitecore_web_index] Committing: Add: 13634; Update:0; DeleteUnique: 0; DeleteGroup: 0
6316 17:27:50 INFO  [Index=sitecore_web_index] Committed
1748 17:27:56 INFO  [Index=sitecore_core_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy executing.
1748 17:27:56 INFO  [Index=sitecore_core_index] History engine is empty. Incremental rebuild returns
9980 17:28:55 INFO  [Index=sitecore_core_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy executing.
9980 17:28:55 INFO  [Index=sitecore_core_index] History engine is empty. Incremental rebuild returns
```

My Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config file:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexUpdateStrategies>
        <intervalAsyncCore type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.IntervalAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <param desc="database">core</param>
          <param desc="interval">00:01:00</param>
          <CheckForThreshold>true</CheckForThreshold>
        </intervalAsyncCore>
        <intervalAsyncMaster type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.IntervalAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <param desc="database">master</param>
          <param desc="interval">00:00:05</param>
          <CheckForThreshold>true</CheckForThreshold>
        </intervalAsyncMaster>
        <manual type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.ManualStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <onPublishEndAsync type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.OnPublishEndAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <param desc="database">web</param>
          <CheckForThreshold>true</CheckForThreshold>
        </onPublishEndAsync>
        <rebuildAfterFullPublish type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.RebuildAfterFullPublishStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <remoteRebuild type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.RemoteRebuildStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
        <syncMaster type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.SynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <param desc="database">master</param>
        </syncMaster>
      </indexUpdateStrategies>
      <databasePropertyStore type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Maintenance.IndexDatabasePropertyStore, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <Key>$(1)</Key>
        <Database>core</Database>
      </databasePropertyStore>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <defaultIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
          <indexAllFields>true</indexAllFields>
          <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.PerExecutionContextAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <param desc="defaultAnalyzer" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.DefaultPerFieldAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
              <param desc="defaultAnalyzer" type="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer, Lucene.Net">
                <param hint="version">Lucene_30</param>
              </param>
            </param>
```

...snip...

```xml
           </analyzer>

          <fieldMap             type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          ...snip...
          </fieldMap>
          <virtualFieldProcessors hint="raw:AddVirtualFieldProcessor">
          ...snip...
          </virtualFieldProcessors>
          <exclude hint="list:ExcludeTemplate">
            <BucketFolderTemplate>{ADB6CA4F-03EF-4F47-B9AC-9CE2BA53FF97}</BucketFolderTemplate>
          </exclude>
          <include hint="list:IncludeField">
            <fieldId>{8CDC337E-A112-42FB-BBB4-4143751E123F}</fieldId>
          </include>-->
          <exclude hint="list:ExcludeField">
          ...snip...
          </exclude>
          <fields hint="raw:AddCustomField">
            <field luceneName="__smallCreatedDate" storageType="yes" indexType="tokenized" format="yyyyMMdd">__created</field>
            <field luceneName="__smallUpdatedDate" storageType="yes" indexType="tokenized" format="yyyyMMdd">__updated</field>
          </fields>
          <fields hint="raw:RemoveSpecialFields">
            <remove type="both">AllTemplates</remove>
            <remove type="both">Created</remove>
            <remove type="both">Editor</remove>
            <remove type="both">Hidden</remove>
            <remove type="both">Icon</remove>
            <remove type="both">Links</remove>
            <remove type="both">Updated</remove>
          </fields>
          <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
          ...snip...
          </fields>
          <fieldReaders type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.FieldReaderMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          ...snip...
          </fieldReaders>
          <indexFieldStorageValueFormatter type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Converters.LuceneIndexFieldStorageValueFormatter, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
          ...snip...
          </indexFieldStorageValueFormatter>
          <indexDocumentPropertyMapper type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.DefaultLuceneDocumentTypeMapper, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
        </defaultIndexConfiguration>
      </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
    <settings>
      <setting name="ContentSearch.CalibrateSizeByDeletes" value="true" />
      <setting name="ContentSearch.ConcurrentMergeSchedulerThreads" value="25" />
      <setting name="ContentSearch.IndexMergeFactor" value="10" />
      <setting name="ContentSearch.LuceneQueryClauseCount" value="1024" />
      <setting name="ContentSearch.MaxDocumentBufferSize" value="10000" />
      <setting name="ContentSearch.MaxMergeDocs" value="10000" />
      <setting name="ContentSearch.MaxMergeMB" value="512" />
      <setting name="ContentSearch.MinMergeMB" value="10" />
      <setting name="ContentSearch.RamBufferSize" value="512" />
      <setting name="ContentSearch.TermIndexInterval" value="256" />
      <setting name="ContentSearch.UseCompoundFile" value="false" />
      <setting name="ContentSearch.WaitForMerges" value="true" />      
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Does anyone have any clue what might be causing the indexer to stall?  I've tried:

- increasing the RAM used for indexing in the config file (the machine has 16GB RAM)
- setting WaitForMerges to false
- using the compound file,
- reducing the number of threads
- increasing the max pool limit in the DB connection strings to 100, 250, 500 and 1000.

I'm absolutely lost as to why the indexing dies like this in SC7 vs SC6.6.  There are no obvious config differences from a fresh SC7 install compared to our SC6.6 indexing settings.

Anyone who can help me get to the bottom of this deserves a medal! Thank you in advance :)

**EDIT**

My is `Caching.DisableCacheSizeLimits` setting is:

```xml
<setting name="Caching.DisableCacheSizeLimits" value="false" />
```

Comment: What is the value of your `Caching.DisableCacheSizeLimits` setting?

Comment: It's `<setting name="Caching.DisableCacheSizeLimits" value="false" />` ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the items {2199D684-1240-4702-B1AD-98CA54A482CD} and {87B6F986-53D4-4D87-9531-6CE90F684DC8}

Are these media items?

See this blog about indexing media

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/04/sitecore-7-indexing-media-with-ifilters

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right.  They are media items (PDF/Office docs).  I've re-installed the iFilters for Adobe and the PDFs now all index!  All that remains is that it chokes on a handful of XLS workbooks- I'm experimenting with the MS Office iFilters to get to the bottom of that. Thank you for your help!